# Nginx as TCP forward proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy

I know I could use some like this:

```
stream {
    upstream ssh {
        server X.X.X.X:22;
    }

    server {
             listen 2222;
             proxy_pass    ssh;
    }
}
```

to proxy pass incoming traffic to port 2222 to another IP's port 22.

Straightforward. But, is there a way to create a dynamic proxy that accepts final destination's hostname and port as parameters?

Something that could be used like this:

```
proxy_hostname:8080?destination_hostname=example.com&destination_port=1111
```

**ngx_stream_core_module** does not accept url parameters. Could nginx be used as a dymanic proxy or only for static tunneling?

I'm asking this because I need a way to hide the IP of a machine firing php mysql requests.

```
mysqli_connect($hostname, ...)
```

right now I cannot specify a proxy for the php script alone, only for the entire machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe with a small script and `fcgiwrap`:

https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/fcgiwrap/

fcgiwrap calls a bash script where you can convert the URI to the program you want to call (mysql) and return the output to nginx as web content.

You could also alter the config of nginx and reload the service. This way you could "dynamicly" open/forward ports. Quite insecure if you make it publicly available.

Comment: I ended doing a sort of NAT with `--with-stream` nginx module. port->IP address¸. I was really surprised discovering that proxy in general cannot be used with parameters but with special applications only.